# how to make a check handle style two different buttons?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx, react-tsx

I'm rendering an array in my quiz component, I can already differentiate which alternative is correct or incorrect, that is, when I click on an alternative, if it is correct it turns green, if not it turns red. But anyway, in short, by my logic, when I click on the wrong alternative, is it possible to render both at the same time (correct and incorrect)?

• my array is like this:

```
const textQuestions = [
  {
    alternatives: [
      { answer: "OPT1", isCorrect: false, alternative: 'A' },
      { answer: "OPT2", isCorrect: false, alternative: 'B' },
      { answer: "OPT3", isCorrect: true, alternative: 'C' },
      { answer: "OPT4", isCorrect: false, alternative: 'D' },
    ]
  }
```

• I am using this state to check which question is being clicked

```
const [selectedAlternative, setSelectedAlternative] = useState<string>();
```

• I used the style property of the button that checks through the ternary operator if the clicked alternative is correct or not

```
{textQuestions[0].alternatives.map(e =>
  <Styles.Button
    onClick={() => setSelectedAlternative(e.alternative)}
    style={{
      backgroundColor:
        selectedAlternative === e.alternative ?
          e.isCorrect
            ? 'green'
            : 'red'
          : ' '
          }}>
            {e.answer}
  </Styles.Button>
)}
```

through this ternary operator logic, is it possible to do a double manipulation of colors on the buttons? But remembering, this logic would only be necessary if the alternative is incorrect

Comment: what's your problem here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize selectedAlternative as null

```
const [selectedAlternative, setSelectedAlternative] = useState<string>(null);
```

Change logic

```
backgroundColor: selectedAlternative !== null ?
  (selectedAlternative === e.alternative && !e.isCorrect) ? "red" : e.isCorrect ?  "green" : "" : ""
```

This is the full code

```
import React from 'react';
const textQuestions = [
  {
    alternatives: [
      { answer: "OPT1", isCorrect: false, alternative: 'A' },
      { answer: "OPT2", isCorrect: false, alternative: 'B' },
      { answer: "OPT3", isCorrect: true, alternative: 'C' },
      { answer: "OPT4", isCorrect: false, alternative: 'D' },
    ]
  }
]

export function App() {
  const [selectedAlternative, setSelectedAlternative] = React.useState(null);
  return textQuestions[0].alternatives.map(e => {
   let backgroundColor = "";

  // easier to debug than ternaries
   if(selectedAlternative !== null) {
      if(selectedAlternative === e.alternative && !e.isCorrect) {
        backgroundColor = "red";
       }
      else if(e.isCorrect){
        backgroundColor = "green";
       }
    }

//  alternative using nested ternaries
//    backgroundColor = selectedAlternative !== null ? (selectedAlternative === e.alternative && !e.isCorrect) ? "red" : e.isCorrect ? "green" : "" : ""

   return <button key={e.alternative}
    onClick={() => setSelectedAlternative(e.alternative)} 
    style={{
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor}}>
            {e.answer}
      </button>
})
}
```

Comment: Change <button> to your <Styles.Button> and you are good to go